# MVC - How can we display several static pages when belonging to the same view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

Using Yii here. But perhaps a more general approach could fit:

Let's say we have a controller/view called: "Theater"

Inside Theater, we wish to have several **static pages** about several *specific* theaters displayed.

PLEASE CONSIDER THE FOLLOWING POINTS (that the DOCUMENTATION don't answer):

**1) The static pages already share the same layout as OTHER views under this application**
**Theater index.php** (that for example, can contain a cmenu with links to each specific theater) already suffers influence from **main.php layout**.

**2) index.php have some HTML that ALL specific pages have.**
Also, **Theater index.php** as some general html elements shared with all *specific* theater pages.

**Question:**
How should we render those specific static pages each time we select a given theater on the menu ?

My first thought was to somehow use the index.php view and inside, call $this->renderPartial('specificTheaterHere'); but I believe this approach doesn't work, because inside renderPartial we should have a variable, but where should we change that variable ? Should we have a controller method for each static page and pass there the variable of a partial view? Would this make sense?

I've read this nice article, still, the question remains.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/22/how-to-display-static-pages-in-yii/

**Note:**
It makes no sense to create a LAYOUT for static pages here, because, they already share the main.php layout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The yiic web-app contains a working example of these static pages. Have you generated that web-app? Did you check that out?

Answer (score 3):

[update] Take a look at Yii layouts as well.

You don't need that, you can use the actions() method to render static pages. In a fresh Yii installation, you can find that in SiteController::actions().

In routes:

```
'page/<view:\w+>' => 'site/page',
```

In SiteController

```
public function actions() {
  return array(
    'page' => array(
      'class' => 'CViewAction',
      'layout' => 'my_layout',
    ),
 );
}
```

Check the full documentation here

Now any static page in /views/site/my_static_page.php can be access by: http://mysite.com/page/my_static_page

Check the full documentation and tutorial here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/22/how-to-display-static-pages-in-yii/

Comment: As you could read on my question, I've read that documentation you have pointing at. That doesn't answer the scenario I'm facing. In order to empathize this better, I've placed numbers on my question, to highlight the points that that documentation don't cover. Thanks again.